# In Gremlin how would I redirect all the edges coming into one vertex, to connect to another vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using Neptune as my graph DB.

Let's say I have a master vertex 'A', and I want to redirect all connections directed towards 'A' into new master vertex 'B'. I know all the edges coming into the master vertex are labeled as 'master_edge'.

Currently I have a mix of python and gremlin code, I'm wondering if there's a way to increase performance by doing this purely in gremlin?

```
vertices_on_deck = g.V(old_master).inE().outV().toList()
          for i, current_vertex in enumerate(vertices_on_deck): 
            if i == 0:
                t = g.addE('master_edge').from_(__.V(current_vertex.id)).to(__.V(new_master))
            else: 
                t.addE('master_edge').from_(__.V(current_vertex.id)).to(__.V(new_master))
          t.iterate()
          g.V(old_master).drop().iterate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge all the queries into one:

```
g.V(old_master).as('oldMaster')
   .inE().outV().addE('master_edge').to(__.V(new_master))
   .select('oldMaster').drop().iterate()
```

Comment: Hmm I found an edge case where the vertices may already be connected to the new master and this will create two edges between the vertex and the new master. Is there a way to only add the edges if that edge label doesn't already exist between those the vertex and new master vertex?

Comment: You can use coalesce step. g.V(old_master).as('oldMaster')
   .inE().outV(). coalesce (out('master_edge').hasId(old_master), .addE('master_edge').to(__.V(new_master)))
   .select('oldMaster').drop().iterate()